# How to change the ownership of the file and access the file after changing the file ownership?

Tags: linux, centos7

I have changed the ownership of the file to user **user19** from user **02042013015** and I am successful in changing the ownership of the file but I don't know how to access the file by user19?

I have done as shown in the screenshot here.[image]

I have changed the mode of directory as shown in the screen shot but still I cannot access the directory1 by user19.[image]

Comment: If `directory1` is indeed a directory, you need to give traversal rights at least to user19, that is `chmod u+x directory1`. What are the rights on the home directory of the 02042... user, that is what `stat -c %A .` return?

Comment: File permission for directory1 at 02042013015 is:  drw-r--r--. 2 user19 02042013015 24 Aug  7 22:03 directory1

Comment: Set permissions to allow traversal with the `chmod uog+x directory1` command.

Answer (score -1):

Using `su`?

```
# adduser testuser
# mkdir testdir
# chown testuser:testuser testdir/
# ls -l | grep test
drwxr-xr-x 2 testuser   testuser     4096 Aug  8 09:55 testdir
```

Now let's make it read for owner only:

```
# chmod 700 testdir/
# ls -l | grep test
drwx------ 2 testuser   testuser     4096 Aug  8 09:55 testdir
```

And try to list it under various users:

```
# su - jmadmin -c 'ls -l testdir'
ls: cannot open directory 'testdir': Permission denied

# su - testuser -c "ls -l testdir"
total 0
```

Please note - parent directories must be readable for the `testuser` user.